# How to create custom library with gradle `compile` support in AndroidStudio?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I'd like to create my own gradle library, that can be compiled into other projects using gradle `compile` statement.

Example from Picasso's README:

> Download the latest JAR or grab via Gradle:
>
> ```
> compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
> ```

I'm developing few applications that share common source: fragments, views, some logic... Sometimes I extend these sources while I'm developing app A, sometimes while I'm developing app B,... And I feel that copy-paste of packages/classes in Android Library Module is not an proper solution.

So I would like to setup my own library, that:

1. it could be easily deployed to as gradle library that could be used by `compile`.
2. I can easily develop/extend it together with currently developed application

*Disclaimer: I had been googling it a lot, but without luck.*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a library across completely separate projects then you'll want to publish your library to repository. Assuming this is open source and you don't mind sharing, you could use JCenter, which is already added as a repository to Android projects by default.

https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/

Comment: Mark is right, you want to build a jar.  You want your own dependency which as Mark pointed out you can publish or if you want locally, just reference a local common project:  compile ':common_project'